# sed '$i d' // Deleting a line with linenumber in var

Tags: bash, sed

Hi i have a linenumber

```
i=10
```

Now I want to delete that line with sed

```
sed '$i d' file
```

But it looke like that this wont work..

any ideas?

Comment: `sed "$i d" file`

Comment: [`sed "$i d" file`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#sed_.27s.2F.24foo.2Fgood_bye.2F.27)

Answer (score 2):

In awk. First test material:

```
$ cat > foo
1
2
3
```

Set the `i`:

```
$ i=2
```

Awk it:

```
$ awk -v line="$i" 'NR!=line' foo
1
3
```

Comment: This is safer than `sed` based approach, because this is immune to shell injection.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i.bak "${i}d" data.txt
```

is what you're looking for.

---

**Notes**

- The `-i` option with sed is used for inplace edit. A backup with extension `.bak` is created.
- The double quotes with sed expands the shell variables

Comment: Has to be `${i}d`, or it tries to expand `$id`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @BenjaminW. : As always pal ! A big thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

To delete second line and show result:

```
sed -e '2d' data.txt
```

So your answer is:

```
sed -e "$i d" file.txt > file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add strong quotes around the quoted variable:

```
i=10
sed ''"$i"' d' file
```